# Quasi-binomial GLM in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I'd like some advice on data I'm analyzing from a factorial-design study in which each sample is a count of 200 urchin eggs that were exposed to various types and concentrations of pollutants, and for each sample we counted how many urchin eggs were fertilized. However, since the 200 eggs for each sample come from the same individual and are exposed to the treatments together as a batch, the 200 counts cannot be considered independent. I've tried fitting multiple models with this data, but each has an obvious flaw to me that I'd like to overcome:

1. The binomial logistic regression assumes that each of the 200 counts are independent, vastly inflating power so that all p-values are very small.
2. Beta models on the proportion of eggs fertilized (at least, the beta model implemented in the R package "betareg") do not accept values that are exactly 0 or 1, of which I have several. This would require rebounding values that are 0 or 1 before fitting the model.
3. An OLS regression with a logit transform of the proportion data has the same issue, requiring me to rebound values to an arbitrary interval within (0, 1).

Another researcher who has worked with similar data has recommended using ordinary linear regression with a transformation of logit(p*0.95 + 0.025) for the raw proportions, but this seems arbitrary to me and complicates the interpretation of the results, which are no longer simply on the log-odds scale.

One thing I did try is a GLM with a quasi-binomial distribution, which ran fine and produced similar qualitative results to the logit-linear model, and accepted proportions that were 0 or 1. I think there's a legitimate basis for using a quasi-binomial, as after rebounding the response to (0.01, 0.99) and logit transforming it, the variance is still higher for treatments with intermediate proportions than with those towards the extremes, and since the logit transform is supposed to stabilize the variance, this seems like a fair reason to use a model that accounts for over-dispersion. Additionally, it seems reasonable that eggs from different urchins could have different probabilities of fertilization success, and we might therefore expect over-dispersion in the data a-priori.

What's surprising to me, however, is that the quasi-binomial implementation in R seems not to be affected by sample size - if I run the model with proportions, the results are exactly the same as if I run the model with the raw counts of fertilized and unfertilized eggs, or if I run the model with proportions and include the number of eggs (again, 200 per sample) in the "weights" argument, or even if I arbitrarily alter the sample size. To me, this is a desirable property, but it's inconsistent with the definitions of the quasi-binomial distribution that I've seen online, which has a parameter for the number of trials just as the binomial distribution does.

My questions, therefore, are:

1. Am I justified in using a quasi-binomial model over a beta model or logit-transformed linear regression, taking into account the possible overdispersion and the need to rebound values that are 0 or 1? I haven't seen this model used in many other studies (not that I've looked much), but it runs and seems to make sense...
2. Why is the quasi-binomial implementation in base R insensitive to sample size? Is this a property specific to R's implementation, or a general property of quasi-binomial GLMs?
3. If the quasi-binomial GLM runs in base R with proportion data and no information on sample size, why isn't the standard binomial model capable of this? Maybe it is, but it's not something I've been able to make work in R.